# Munkres Topology book Purple vs Green

Tags: general-topology, book-recommendation

This may seem as an odd question. But I'm taking a topology course this semester and I found a seller that sells the book for 70% of the store price. But the book is in purple, after doing some research I saw that the purple book is way cheaper than the green (classic edition) one. Is there a lot of differences between the books?

Comment: I have the purple book and it is perfectly fine.

Comment: I went with the green one after all, found the purple one for the same prices as the green (both were used).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting a review from the [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131816292) website:

> [$\ldots$] if you choose to order the economy edition (purple cover) then you should know that the quality of the paper is very poor. Everything is readable and its exactly the same (as far as I can tell) as the hardcover but the pages themselves are a dull grey color and not very thick or resilient. The best I can describe it as its the same paper that is used in high school workbooks that you are supposed to write in and then tear out the pages and hand them in. Most people wont care (frankly I don't anymore) so I wont remove any stars from this otherwise excellent text, but just be forewarned if you are that kind of person who is bothered by such things.